# Editing NSString when a specific symbol appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have an NSString I am receiving that can be any number of characters long. What I would like to achieve is to read through all of the characters until I find a '/' forward slash, then replace that and any character after that with the '+' plus symbol.

I am not sure how to proceed with doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something simply like this:

```
NSString *longString = ... // your long string
NSRange slashRange = [longString rangeOfString:@"/"];
if (slashRange.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSString *plusString = [[longString substringToIndex:slashRange.location] stringByAppendingString:@"+"];
} else {
    // oops - no slash in the string 
}
```

I just realized you might want something different. Do you want to replace the slash and everything with a single `+` or do you want to replace each character after the slash with a `+`?

Comment: Sorry I could have been clearer, including the Slash and anything after it replace with a single + i.e. 12/45432 would be 12+

Comment: OK, then the answer I gave is what you want.

Comment: Looks like `plusString` goes out of scope as soon as it's created. You might want to declare it at the top.

Comment: @Caleb I did that on purpose since I didn't know how the OP wanted to deal with there being no slash.

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code first checks the entire string for your character.  If it finds one then you get the substring to that index and create an NSMutableString around it.  Then just add "+" signs until you are at the same length as the original string.  That should do the trick, although there are likely easier ways that I do not know.

```
NSUInteger location = [yourString rangeOfString:@"/"].location;
if(location != NSNotFound)
{
    int length = [yourString length];
    yourString = [yourString substringToIndex:location];
    NSMutableString *returnString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[yourString substringToIndex:location]];
    while([returnString length] <= length)
    {
        [returnString appendString:@"+"];
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `NSUInteger`, not `int` for the `location` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers might be better for your situation, but for completeness I will mention regular expressions.

```
NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: @"\/.*" 
                                                                       options: 0 
                                                                         error: NULL];
yourString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString: yourString 
                                             options: 0 
                                               range: NSMakeRange(0, [yourString length]) 
                                        withTemplate: @"\+"];
```